# How to represent a dynamic list of ranges?

Tags: python, range

When printing pages from a document, for example, you can specify the specific page numbers you want to print using this shorthand notation:

```
1, 3, 4-7, 9-
```

And in a 12-page document this would print pages

```
1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12
```

How can I represent such a structure in Python so that I can query whether a specific "page number" (this is not limited to printing; that was an example) is in the range and also loop over the range?

These things would be easy if they were in a flattened list as in the second example (and string processing to convert it to that would be trivial), but the open-ended ranges pose a problem. It must not be flattened until the last minute.

Comment: Does a list of [1, 3, 4,5,6, 9...end of pages] not work? I'm sure you can think of something a little better like a dict for O(1) access, but I don't see your problem.

Comment: @EugeneK: It would, but the "end of pages" can vary, and the range needs to be usable on sets of a different length (so the list can't be precomputed).

Comment: why not just have a `numOfPages` and a for loop add the elements from the marker to the end? You just change numOfPages when a new 'book' is added. I'm sorry, can you clarify a little bit more in the question what you want. Are you looking for a more elegant answer than that?

Comment: Optimal solution probably uses [interval trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) for managing ranges. See [`intervaltree`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a generator:

```
import itertools

def parse_ranges(ranges):
    for chunk in ranges.split(', '):
        if '-' not in chunk:
            chunk = chunk + '-' + chunk  # Turns 7 into 7-7 

        start, end = chunk.split('-')

        if end:
            yield from range(int(start), int(end) + 1)
        else:
            yield from itertools.count(int(start))
```

You can enforce a max page number when you iterate over it:

```
for page in parse_ranges('1, 3, 4-7, 9-'):
    if page > 20:
        break

    print(page)
```

Or do that separately:

```
def cap(iterable, maximum):
    for n in iterable:
        if n > maximum:
            break

        yield n

pages = list(cap(parse_ranges('1, 3, 4-7, 9-'), 20))
```

Comment: Looks good, but membership testing is strange. If I do `x in parse_ranges('<any range>')`, if `x` is indeed in the range it returns True, but if not the interpreter just hangs (Python 3.4.0). Am I missing something fundamental about how generators work?

Comment: @rvighne: Membership on generators won't work well if they're not finite. Convert the generator into a list and test membership with that.

Comment: Will I have to do that manually in a loop like the one you provided, or is there a better way? (As expected, the `list` constructor doesn't work. Can I somehow specify a maximum to the constructor?)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you could use a list of tuples. `(1,1)` means page number 1, `(4, 7)` means pages 4, 5, 6 and 7. The tricky part is representing "from this page to the end". However, if you have the access to the number of pages, this can be solved by using `float("inf")`. The flattening function would then look like this:

```
def flatten_ranges(ranges, number_of_pages):
    flattened_list = []
    for item in ranges:
        page = item[0]
        while page <= item[1] and page <= number_of_pages:
            flattened_list.append(page)
            page += 1
    return flattened_list
```

Comment: @rvighne actually, you can use any string. `x > y` returns true for any string `x` and number `y`. But `float("inf")` is a more clean solution ;)

Comment: So basically all I need is a marker for "and now go until the end." Thanks for showing me that.

Comment: You could also do this with generators and `itertools.islice`.

Comment: @Blender: Could you please elaborate? [These docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) don't show me the value of using that.

Comment: @rvighne: My mistake, for some reason I thought `islice` enforced a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon my noobish attempt using list of tuples as the pages

```
pages=[(1,1),(3,3),(4,7),(8,)]

def find_page(pages,page):
    for p in pages:
        if len(p)==1:
            if page >= p[0]:
                return True
            else:
                break
        if p[0]==p[1]:
            if page==p[0]:
                return True
        elif page >= p[0] and page <= p[1]:
            return True
```